# Does OpenSSL support IPV6?

Tags: openssl, ipv6

I have an C app running on Windows, Linux, Solaris and HPUX that calls `SSL_read()` and `SSL_write()` over a socket. Is this functionality supported over IPV6 in any version of OpenSSL?

From my searching it does not seem obvious. I have found some INET6 definitions in the 1.0 release BIO code. I have also read somewhere that to get IPV6 working you do the normal socket calls specifying INET6 and then use `BIO_set_fd()` to get IPV6 working. Is this correct?

Comment: If you can use normal socket API then it should work out of the box. OpenSSL own BIO API itself has also IPv6 support but for that libraries should be compiled with OPENSSL_USE_IPV6 1 option.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem.  I have to write a non blocking TLS server using IPV6.  This is basically what you want to use:

```
/* Create a socket BIO attached to an already existing socket 
 * descriptor.  The socket descriptor will be closed when the BIO is 
 * destroyed. */ 
bio = BIO_new_socket(sd, BIO_CLOSE);
```

Of course, as it says, you need to create the socket first.  That's taken from "Network Security with OpenSSL", which is a bit out of date.  You need that book to use OpenSSL properly, get it.

This is particularly frustrating there isn't direct IPV6 support, because the IPV6 BSD socket interface (as awful as it is - as awful as the IPV4 interface) is 100% compatible with IPV4.  In fact, I don't even program using IPV4 structures anymore since I've learned the IPV6 BSD library interface.

IPV4 addresses are simply ::ffff:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the IPV4 address.  Here's a function that will convert a struct in_addr to a struct in6_addr:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// NOTE: it's safe for ((void *)pin) == ((void*) pout) //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct in6_addr *sockaddr_in_to_6 (struct in_addr *pin, struct in6_addr *pout)
{
  // as IPV6 IPV4 address is stored as 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:FFFF:AABB:CCDD
  // where IPV4 address is AA.BB.CC.DD
  pout->s6_addr[0x0c] = ( (struct in6_addr *)pin)->s6_addr[0x00];
  pout->s6_addr[0x0d] = ( (struct in6_addr *)pin)->s6_addr[0x01];
  pout->s6_addr[0x0e] = ( (struct in6_addr *)pin)->s6_addr[0x02];
  pout->s6_addr[0x0f] = ( (struct in6_addr *)pin)->s6_addr[0x03];

  pout->s6_addr[0x00] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x01] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x02] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x03] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x04] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x05] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x06] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x06] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x07] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x08] = 0x00;
  pout->s6_addr[0x09] = 0x00;

  pout->s6_addr[0x0a] = 0xFF;
  pout->s6_addr[0x0b] = 0xFF;

  return pout;
}
```

You'll never need to use struct in_addr again with that and it's entirely compatible with IPV4.  When using an IPV4 address encoded within the IPV6 structures, the actual network traffic is still IPV4 - at least under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details about OpenSSL and IPv6, but from a general standpoint, OpenSSL for TLS connections operates in the TCP layer, which is the same for IPv4 and IPv6. No changes should affect your application.